# сумма чисел java script

Tags: javascript

У меня есть кнопка при нажатии на которую должно прибавляться число в лобальную переменную

```
 var sum='';

   out+=`<div class="val-plus" data-id="${pack.id}" ><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>`; 

$('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);

function plusGoods(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    for(var id in sum){
        sum=sum[id]+1;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

функция выполняется, но почему то когда в консоле проверяю, все равно все пусто.
Помогите пожалуйста,в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `console.log(sum);` нужно делать внутри функции `plusGoods` - сумма ведь вычисляется только по клику на `.val-plus`

Comment: Да, и `for(var id in sum) { sum=sum[id]+1; }` - это что-то очень подозрительное